# React PropTypes: Allow different types of PropTypes for one prop

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a component that receives a prop for its size. The prop can be either a string or a number ex: `"LARGE"` or `17`.

Can I let `React.PropTypes` know that this can be either one or the other in the propTypes validation?

If I don't specify the type I get a warning:

> prop type `size` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from
> React.PropTypes.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    size: React.PropTypes
}
```

Answer (score 824, accepted):

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.number
]),
```

Learn more: [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm getting random errors when run my Jest tests setting static Proptypes in my classes: `ReferenceError: oneOfType is not defined` — any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: are u sure u have correctly imported `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` ?

Comment: hey there Pawel -- yes, this is how we import them: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: 2019 - use PropTypes.oneOf

Comment: @Imdad: `oneOf` is not used for type checking, only to limit the actual value of the property. Thus keep on using `PropTypes.oneOfType`.

Answer (score 44):

For documentation purpose, it's better to list the string values that are legal:

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.oneOf([ 'SMALL', 'LARGE' ]),
]),
```

Comment: This is the way to do it when the prop should be an Enum. You can even provide an Enum to the `oneOf` method.

Comment: how to show it in suggestions for when the size option like you press ctrl+space and suggestion come those want to set then

Answer (score 24):

This might work for you:

```
height: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 6):

Here is pro example of using multi proptypes and single proptype.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { string, shape, array, oneOfType } from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    const { title, data } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        {title}
        <br />
        {data}
      </>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Define component props
 */
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  data: oneOfType([array, string, shape({})]),
  title: string,
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -7):

```
import React from 'react';              <--as normal
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';     <--add this as a second line

    App.propTypes = {
        monkey: PropTypes.string,           <--omit "React."
        cat: PropTypes.number.isRequired    <--omit "React."
    };

    Wrong:  React.PropTypes.string
    Right:  PropTypes.string
```

Comment: Yes, PropTypes lives in its own package now, but that does not answer the question...

Comment: Completely not relevant to the question