# Can I mix a type and a value in PropTypes oneOf?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is it possible to use `PropTypes.oneOf` to enforce the presence of either a specific type or a string literal?

Example:

```
display: PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.bool, 'autohide']),
```

Or is it simply treating PropTypes.bool as whatever literal value it returns? Couldn't find any reference to this in the official documentation, so I'm assuming it doesn't work as I expect it to work. It doesn't raise an error, though.

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: Worth checking [React PropTypes : Allow different types of PropTypes for one prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808428/react-proptypes-allow-different-types-of-proptypes-for-one-prop)

Comment: @Rishabh are you sure? Any proof?

Answer (score 27):

You can nest `oneOf()` into `oneOfType()` like that

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.bool,
    PropTypes.oneOf(['autohide'])
])
```

Comment: Just saw this: [How to get nested proptypes? I want the prop to be a specific string ('xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl') or any number · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/2d086d0efa44d1a3ad10645dfd30c469)

Comment: Makes sense via documentation, although I don't love shoving an array in there just for the sake of one literal value. Rather just spell out booth boolean values, I guess.

Comment: @YoniWeisbrod Exactly, in this case! 

Comment: docs showing different example for `oneOfType` - with mixing type + `PropTypes.instanceOf`

Comment: @skyboyer `instanceOf` won't work in this case, coz OP is looking to validate against a specific value.

Comment: it was comment on "is there a doc for this?". there is no explicit doc section but sample says it's possible

Comment: I miss TypeScript :)

Comment: @YoniWeisbrod For some reason, I hate TypeScript - it's bringing in the Java to the JavaScript, which should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's possible, but not directly. Actually you can have different `PropTypes` this way:

```
display: PropTypes.oneOf([
  true,
  false,
  'autohide'
]),
```

You know that the `PropTypes.bool` is going to be either `true` or `false`. For an advanced use of validation, see the CustomValidation here: [`customArrayProp`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes).

Reference: [Typechecking With PropTypes – React](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: Thanks - ya, I'm aware that I can supply literal values. But I wanted to see if it was possible to mix. CustomArray is an interesting idea, thanks.

Comment: @YoniWeisbrod Yep, here: [How to get nested proptypes? I want the prop to be a specific string ('xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl') or any number · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/2d086d0efa44d1a3ad10645dfd30c469).

Comment: @YoniWeisbrod After our discussion, it looks like you would be going with my solution. You wanna accept this answer? 