# PropType for string convertible to number?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is there a prop type that accepts number strings? If I'm passing the prop directly to a DOM element, it doesn't care if I use prop={1} or prop="1", but how do I make a matching PropType that accepts it, other than using a custom callback?

I asked this before but it got closed as duplicate of [React PropTypes : Allow different types of PropTypes for one prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808428/react-proptypes-allow-different-types-of-proptypes-for-one-prop), but I'm not interested in accepting ANY string - I only want strings that are parsed as numbers.

Comment: Then check if `! isNaN()` before passing it as prop.

Comment: You mean using a custom proptype checker?

Comment: Some times you just have to go with what you know. Don't let perfection get in the way of whatever you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want strings that are parsed as numbers.

This is possible using a [custom validator](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) for your prop.

```js
const App = (props) => {
  return <span>{props.number}</span>
}

App.propTypes = {
  number: function (props, propName, componentName) {
    // Check if not a number.
    if (isNaN(props[propName])) {
      return new Error(
        "Invalid prop `" +
          propName +
          "` supplied to" +
          " `" +
          componentName +
          "`. Validation failed."
      );
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App number="a" />, // error
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```